# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateAxisRenderer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, jqplot

I've got a problem with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var min=graficoMin;
  var max=graficoMax;
  var line3=graficoMeteo;

  dayMin = dataMin;
  dayMax = dataMax; 
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [max, min], {
      title:'Temperatura',
      series:[
        { label: 'Temp Max', color:'#FF3333' },
        { label: 'Temp Min', color:'#0033FF' }],
      seriesDefaults:{
        markerOptions:{size:6}},
      legend: { show: true }, 
      axes:{
      xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          tickOptions:{ formatString:'%b %#d' },
          min:dayMin,
          max:dayMax
        },
      yaxis:{
          min:-15,
          max:50,
          tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%.0f° C'
          }
        }
      },
      highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
      },
      cursor: {
        show: false
      }
  });

  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line3], {
      title:'Meteo',
      seriesDefaults:{
        pointLabels:{
            show: false,
            edgeTolerance: 5,   
        },
        markerOptions:{size:6}},     
      axes:{
      xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          tickOptions:{ formatString:'%b %d' },
          min:dayMin,
          max:dayMax
        },
        yaxis:{
            ticks:[[1, "Ghiaccio"],[2,"Neve"],[3,"Temporale"],[4,"Pioggia"]]
        }
      },
      highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
      },
      cursor: {
        show: false
      }
  });
});
```

If I open the page by clicking a link it won't work with because the line

> renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,

return this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateAxisRenderer' of undefined

But it'll work if I go to the page by url.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I googled around without success.

Comment: Solved with a workaround: i've change  
__`<a href='...'> `__  
with href to external link  
__`<a href='...' rel='external'>__`  
So the now page work like I go there by url.